# How to achieve Dijkstra's O(X+Y) in time complexity if edge weights always is 1 or 2?

Tags: graphs, time-complexity

If we were to have a connected directed graph that has **X** edges and **Y** vertices and all the edge weights are either 1 or 2. Would it be possible to somehow achieve a time complexity of **O(X+Y)** using Dijkstra's algorithm, when finding the shortest path between the two given vertices **A** and **B** from the graph.

Comment: Think where does the $O(\log n)$ in Dijkstra comes from and figure out how to deal with that given this special restriction.

Answer (score 2):

If all edge weights are $1$ or $2$ you can have a linear time algorithm to find shortest path.
First perform a BFS and for every edge $(u,v)$ of weight $2$ add an vertice at the middle $w$ so that you now have two edges of weight one $(u,w)$ and $(w,v)$.

After this BFS your new graph have all it edges of weight $1$ and have at most $2X$ edges.

Now perform an other BFS on this graph to find the shortest path. It gives you a complexity of $O(2X+Y)$.
Thus the total complexity is $O(X+Y)$

Comment: After the first BFS, the new graph has a different number of vertices, doesn't it? Something in [Y, 2Y)? That still gets the same end answer, but it should be O(2X + 2Y) -> O(X + Y). Is that wrong?